# Does FileInputStream incorrectly implement InputStream?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, fileinputstream, standard-library

[The docs for `InputStream.read(bytes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) say "This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown."

However, `java.io.FileInputStream` extends `java.io.InputStream`
and [the docs for `FileInputStream.read(bytes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) state no such guarantee:

```
 * Reads up to {@code b.length} bytes of data from this input
 * stream into an array of bytes. This method blocks until some input
 * is available.
```

In practice, `FileInputStream` can indeed return before all the input is available, so it seems both the docs and the implementation do not follow the contract of `InputStream`.

Is this a bug? Is it a known bug?

**UPDATE**: to clarify: `System.in` is a `FileInputStream`. I am seeing `System.in.read(buf)` return a nonzero int that is *neither* all of the bytes, *nor* `-1`. If I use `System.in.readNBytes(buf, 0, theNumberOfBytesIAmExpecting)` then I get all the bytes the sender is sending.

Comment: How do you define a File?

Comment: Louis’s answer is correct.  `read` has never been specified to return any particular number of bytes, in either class.  `readNBytes` is specifically guaranteed to return the number of requested bytes, unless EOF is reached first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the situation is more subtle, - `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` just delegates to `InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`

And for `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` it seems that the contract/promise broken (or at least different).

For [`InputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) the documentation states:

> The default implementation of this method blocks **until the requested amount of input data len has been read**, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown. Subclasses are encouraged to provide a more efficient implementation of this method.

(and it is implemented this way: - the requested amount of data is always read)

For [`FileInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) - there is no such promise (and implementation may not read all the requested amount).

Many other high-level methods delegate to `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` and I would consider that at least for this method the promise of `InputStream` (to read either the requested amount or till the end of the steam) is broken in `FileInputStream` and it creates confusion.

Comment: Any sentence that starts with “The default implementation of this method” is not part of the contract.  The method contract starts with: “Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read.”  That seems very clear to me.

Comment: The _default_ implementation working that way is not remotely the same thing as the contract saying that it has to work that way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a contract violation, and is therefore not a bug.

The doc for `InputStream` specifies that it blocks until "input data is available," which is not the same thing as "all the input is available."

If you're referring to the "end of file" aspect, continue to read the Javadoc for `FileInputStream.read`, which specifies

> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, **or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the file has been reached.**

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added a clarification to the question.

Comment: Yes.  The behavior you describe is perfectly compliant with the contract.  Note also the `InputStream` first sentence: "Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer."